# Should I borrow or copy my small data types?

Tags: rust

```
struct Vec {
    data: [f32; 3],
}

impl Vec {
    fn dot(&self, other: &Vec) -> f32 {
        ..
    }
    // vs
    fn dot(self, other: Vec) -> f32 {
        ..
    }
}
```

I am currently writing a vector math library and I am wondering if I should borrow or copy my vector types.

At the moment I implement `Copy` for `Vec` which makes the API a bit nicer because you don't have to write `&` all the time.

But it requires much more complex constraints, because now all my constraints also need to satisfy `Copy`.

Which one potentially yields better performance and why?

Which one potentially yields better ergonomics and why?

Edit:

I have created a small [microbenchmark](https://github.com/MaikKlein/vector_bench)

```
test bref_f32 ... bench:   2,736,055 ns/iter (+/- 364,885)
test bref_f64 ... bench:   4,872,076 ns/iter (+/- 436,928)
test copy_f32 ... bench:   2,708,568 ns/iter (+/- 31,162)
test copy_f64 ... bench:   4,890,014 ns/iter (+/- 553,050)
```

It seems that there is no difference between `ref` and `copy` for this example in terms of performance.

`Copy` seems to yield better ergonomics for library users.

Comment: Are you really sure you want to ask about "idiomatic" and not "performance" or "simplifying the bounds"? Because idioms are very much *subjective*, and I am afraid that both alternatives could be recommended and no definite objective answer exists.... in which case your question is primed for closure (Primarily Opinion-based).

Comment: @MatthieuM. I assumed there were some guide lines for what idiomatic Rust code should look like, I rephrased the question and added an example.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Rust is not a pure academic language with lofty aesthetics goals and a singular purpose. Rust is a systems programming language, which implies pragmatism.

The general rule of thumb is that your interface should correctly document *ownership*:

- pass by value when you give up ownership
- pass by reference (possibly mutable) when you temporarily relinquish ownership

however the `Copy` trait is the perfect example of pragmatism at play. It recognizes that passing by reference can be cumbersome (does anyone want to type `(&1 + &x) * &y`?) and therefore creates an escape hatch for types that do not need to be affine (ie, no special action on destruction).

As a result, semantically, if your type can be *guaranteed* to be and remain `Copy`, then marking it as such gives users some leeway on its use which can improve ergonomics. I would encourage you to mark it, then, though with the reminder that later removing the `Copy` trait would be a backward incompatible change.

Once a type is `Copy`, I would not hesitate to take advantage of the fact and pass it by value. After all, if the type is never passed by value then there was no point in making it `Copy` in the first place.

---

The only caveat would be performance reason.

`Copy` does *not* force a copy, it merely allows it. This means that an optimizer has all latitude to use a copy... or not.

For small types the performance is unlikely to be much different whatever happens; for bigger types I would encourage benchmarking various interfaces if performance matters. `Vec` is only 1.5x the size of a pointer/reference on 64-bits architectures, so it really is in a gray area. Sometimes copying will be slower (larger copy) but sometimes the benefits of having a local copy will enable optimizations that would not be triggered with a pointer.

However such benchmarking is fraught with peril, notably because it hugely depends on whether the function is inlined, or not (given more or less leeway for removing copies).

Answer (score 5):

I'd recommend borrowing in this scenario because it does not seem like ownership is a concern. So, I guess your code would look like

```
struct Vec {
    data: [f32; 3],
}

impl Vec {
    fn dot(&self, other: &Vec) -> f32 {..}
}
```

Comment: Could you explain why you would recommend that?

Comment: I'd recommend it because it uses more memory to create a whole new vector, which is what happens when you copy a vector. If you needn't create a new vector, don't.

Comment: *which is what happens when you copy a vector* — which can be up to the whims of an optimizing compiler, if it decides that it could be simplified.